# Azure Graph with B2C AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

When I try to acquire a token from my Azure AD B2C app using

`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory - 3.13.1`
`Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient - 2.1.0`

like this:

```
var authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/6b7403d6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";
var clientId = "59e08b82-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var appKey = "XXXX-MyAppKey-XXXX";
var graphUri = "https://graph.windows.net/6b7403d6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri, false);
var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, myAppKey);

var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphUri, clientCred);
```

I get

```
[AdalServiceException: AADSTS70001: Application '59e08b82-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is not supported for this API version.
```

Is there a library I can use in ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET 4.5) to get access to the B2C Active directory I created using the UI of the [new Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), not PowerShell from this [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/)?

(The xxxx's are just for privacy here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need power shell creation any more, MSFT have given permission to add a new application in Azure AD(not in azure b2c), which can be used to access Graph API in azure B2C. You need to follow below steps IN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Only for Deleting access for your graph api you need to do some power-shell magic...

Answer (score 0):

The example you referenced: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/
only uses powershell to set up a Service Principal.

After you have the Service Principal, you can use that in your code to access the Graph API. The example does this from a console app, but this works as well from MVC 5

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if you are answering my question. My description explains my setup. Thus, the error. I was making sure people do not answer regarding that popular example.

Comment: Good point, can you update the question a bit, is there a library: I don't think so.
Is there a Library to Access B2C, yes that's the Graph API, but it needs a powershell setup